Training LLM uses unexpected amount of GPU memory
I'm training model with self-implemented training loops. A 1.5B Qwen2 occupies 40G of GPU memory. When I did the same training using llama factory, it only takes about 24G.
I tried to delete some objects during training, but things remain the same. Any suggestions about how to save more VRAM?
def init_model(model_name, hyper_param):

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, torch_dtype = "auto", attn_implementation = "flash_attention_2")

    peft_config = LoraConfig(r = 128,
                             lora_alpha = 32,
                             lora_dropout = 0.05,
                             bias = "none",
                             task_type = "CAUSAL_LM",
                             target_modules = ["q_proj", "k_proj", "v_proj", "o_proj", "gate_proj", "up_proj", "down_proj"])

    model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)

    return model


def init_dataloader(model_name, data, hyper_param):

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

    dataset_train = PretrainDataset(1024, pad_id = 151643)

    contents = data["content"].to_list()[-50:]
    
    for t in tqdm(contents, desc = "Crafting Dataset"):
    
        max_length = len(t) * 3
    
        tokenized_text = tokenizer(t, return_tensors = "pt", max_length = max_length, truncation = True, padding = False)
        tokenized_text = tokenized_text["input_ids"]
        dataset_train.add_data(tokenized_text)
    
    print(len(dataset_train), " of data points")
    
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size = hyper_param["batch_size"], shuffle = True)

    return train_loader

def train(model, train_loader, optimizer, accelerator, lr_scheduler):

    model.train()

    for step, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        with accelerator.accumulate(model):
            
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(**batch)
            
            loss = outputs.loss
            accelerator.backward(loss)
            optimizer.step()
            
            lr_scheduler.step()

            if accelerator.sync_gradients:
                print(loss)
                
                del loss


def training_loop(model_name, data, hyper_param):

    model = init_model(model_name, hyper_param)
    optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr = 5e-5)
    train_loader = init_dataloader(model_name, data, hyper_param)
    accelerator = Accelerator(gradient_accumulation_steps = hyper_param["gradient accumulation"])
    
    model, optimizer, train_loader = accelerator.prepare(model, optimizer, train_loader)


    lr_schedular = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer = optimizer, num_warmup_steps = hyper_param["warmup"], num_training_steps = len(train_loader) * hyper_param["epochs"])

    
    for _ in tqdm(range(hyper_param["epochs"]), desc = "training progress"):

        train(model, train_loader, optimizer, accelerator, lr_schedular)

        break


if __name__ == "__main__":

    hyperparameters = {"gradient accumulation" : 256,
                       "batch_size" : 2,
                       "warmup" : 10,
                       "epochs" : 1}

    training_loop("../model/Qwen2-1.5B-Instruct", data, hyperparameters)

Where I did wrong? How to fix it and use less memory?

Check to make sure you are only training the lora parameters and not the full set of model weights
